# How do I make a textarea keep the line breaks without showing the br tags from a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to write paragraphs and store it in the MySQL database and it can be outputted on a page with all the appropriate line breaks but how do i make it so my text-area for editing the blog post shows the line breaks instead of showing BR tags and requiring me to write BR tags to create a new paragraph.

Here is my text-area:

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; padding-left: 10px; outline: none;" type="text" name="para" rows="5"><?php echo $row['Para']; ?></textarea>
```

Thank you for any help I have been stuck on this for months

Comment: Store the value as the user entered it: with newlines and not with `<br>` tags. Only pass the value through `nl2br()` when you output it as HTML.

Comment: @rickdenhaan please check my answer bellow what do you think about my solution?

Comment: @WardNsour that can only be considered a "fix after the fact", for what has been done fundamentally wrong here to begin with.

Comment: @WardNsour Your answer replaces the string "br" with a HTML `<br>` tag. That is unlikely to be what OP needs, but I'll let them judge that.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$str = 'bring me to live br from this world br to stackoverflow';
$pattern = '/\bbr\b/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '<br>', $str);
```

> Output: 
>  bring me to live 
> from this world 
> to stackoverflow

so your code should look like this

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; padding-left: 10px; outline: none;" type="text" name="para" rows="5"><?php echo preg_replace('/\bbr\b/i','<br>',$row['Para']); ?></textarea>
```

Highly recommend you to read about [Pattern Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) also.